# Repeating an object hundreds of thousands of times

Tags: python, mesh

I want to represent vector field data by arrows, one arrow representing one sample, for scientific visualization. The vector field is sampled unstructured, i.e. where there is data rather than on a regular grid).

I have a very nice low-polycount arrow object to use, but now need an efficient way to replicate the arrow in the ~100,000 sample positions and rotate each to align with the sampled vector directions, and rescale to represent magnitude.

NumPy code to transform the vertex coordinates takes miliseconds, but I don't know how to efficiently do this with Blender. In particular, I would like the arrow's materials to be replicated correctly as well as the mesh, so I think that I cannot just use from_pydata?

The simple examples I have found online for duplicating objects are so slow as to be infeasible to use with the large number of replications. What is the correct way to do this with Blender+Python? (A method to do this with Blender+C/C++ would be great as well).

Thank you for any help you may have (I am an experienced programmer, but new to Blender.)

Comment: Try array modifier

Comment: Thank you, mr. car. Would you care to elaborate what you mean by that?